# A question, in a certain context, on the meaning of complete, nesting, and replace

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

In

```
my_Orders = PreviousOrders %>%
  full_join(select(Other_Orders_Redist, Type, Date, ReValue = Previous_Sales, PreviousWeeks),
            by = c('Type', 'Send_Date' = 'Date', 'WeeksPrior')) %>%
  mutate(Previous_Sales = ifelse(is.na(ReValue), Previous_Sales, ReValue)) %>%
  select(Type, Date = Send_Date, Previous_Sales, PreviousWeeks) %>%
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(HistoricalSales$Date), max(Preious_weeks_orders$Send_Date), by="week"), nesting(Type, PreviousWeeks)) %>%
  filter(Date <= FinalWeek + weeks(PreviousWeeks + 1)) %>%
  mutate(PreviousWeeks = paste0('Orders_Min_', PreviousWeeks + 1, '_Weeks')) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
  spread(PreviousWeeks, Previous_Sales)
```

what do the following lines mean? Can someone explain in the context of the example?

Line #1

```
complete(Date = seq.Date(min(HistoricalSales$Date), max(Previous_weeks_orders$Send_Date), by="week"), nesting(Type,PreviousWeeks)) %>%
```

Line #2

```
replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
```

My guess is that the `replace` replaces all of the NA in the data frame by 0 but I am not sure. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: If you type `replace` without parentheses in a console, you'll see the source, which is very short. It's a little weird to call it on a whole data frame, though it does work because of matrix coercion and subsetting. A more idiomatic way in dplyr would be `mutate_all(coalesce, 0)`

Comment: The `complete` adds rows for the combinations of the elements supplied. The columns wrapped in `nesting` are treated as a single element. Simpler example: `tibble(x = 1:3, y = 4:6, z = c(7, 8, 8)) %>% complete(x, nesting(y, z))`

Comment: @alistaire Thank you. What does the replace in the statement do? Is my guess correct? As regards the second example, I see there are 3 possibilities for x and 3 for (y,z) since y and z are nested, and so complete yields 9 rows. But if I do complete(x) - that is no nesting at all - expecting 27 rows (3x3x3), I get just 3 rows.

Comment: @alistaire I didn't understand this. "If you type replace without parentheses in a console, you'll see the source, which is very short. " Can you please elaborate?

Comment: To see the source code for `replace`, in an R session, run `replace`, and it'll print `function (x, list, values) 
{
    x[list] <- values;
    x
}`

Comment: `complete` does combinations of levels between variables, not within, so `complete(x)` doesn't change the input data frame. More interesting might be `tibble(x = c(1, 1, 3), y = 4:6, z = c(7, 8, 8)) %>% complete(x, y)`

Comment: @alistaire I am sorry I don't quite understand what you meant right above on complete. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Honestly, you just need to play around with it a little to understand it. The examples in [the docs](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) are a good place to start.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you. From what I see, complete(x,y) just adds to the data frame for each value of x a row comprising that value of x and those values of y with which it has not been associated before the complete is applied. If there are other columns apart from x and y, they are populated with NA for the new rows.